# How to check if two arrays of equal size have the same values in C? (complexity O(n) )

Tags: c, arrays, permutation

Edit: the values of the elements range from 0 to 99 from 0 to 99.
Is that even possible? I've tried to use the following code, but it's obviously wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scrambled(unsigned int a[], unsigned int b[], unsigned int len) {
    if (len = 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int sumA, sumB, i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sumA += a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sumB += b[i];
        }
        if (sumA == sumB) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed that two arrays with the same sum of values would also have the same values, but this is not the case. `{2,2}` and `{3,1}` have the same sum, but not the same values.

Is there any way I can check if, in another words, one array is a permutation of another with linear complexity time?

Comment: You can consider 1) Quicksorting both arrays and then just comparing corresponding elements, or 2) Convert each array into a min-heap and subsequently pop elements and compare.

Comment: In the case of quicksorting, the complexity wouldn't be O(n), right?

Comment: Oh, apologies. I wasn't aware that the O(n) was a constraint, I thought you had mentioned it as being the complexity of YOUR method.

Comment: Assuming you mean equal values in the same positions, just loop through comparing the values at each index and stop when you find a mismatch. If you get all the way through, they match.

Comment: The values don't need to be at the same position necessarily. {1,2,3} and {3,2,1} have the same values.

Comment: It would be impossible to compare two unordered arrays in time less than O(n log n).  It would only be O(n) if the arrays were already sorted.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I do not think so. It is impossible, if your algorithm uses the ordering.

Comment: @Lyesmith What is the range of the stored values? The complete `int` range?

Comment: There is another obvious flaw in the posted code: `if (len = 0)` will set `len` to `0`. The function always returns `1`.

Comment: @Lyesmith: can you accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use hash in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

bool isEqual(int a1[], int a2[], int len) {
  using namespace std;
  unordered_set<int> s1(a1, a1 + len); //O(n)
  unordered_set<int> s2(a2, a2 + len); // O(n)
  return s1 == s2; // O(n)
}

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  int a1[5] = {5,2,3,4,1};
  int a2[5] = {1,3,2,5,4};
  std::cout << isEqual(a1, a2, sizeof(a1) / sizeof(int)) << std::endl;

  int a3[5] = {0,2,3,4,5};
  int a4[5] = {1,6,2,5,4};
  std::cout << isEqual(a3,a4, sizeof(a3) / sizeof(int)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If there exists same value in your data, exchange unordered_set to `unordered_multiset`

In addition:
    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp

> Complexity Proportional to N calls to operator== on value_type, calls
>   to the predicate returned by key_eq, and calls to the hasher returned
>   by hash_function, in the average case, proportional to N2 in the worst
>   case where N is the size of the container.

More fast plans:
 implements a **custom** hash table according to your data. for example, what is the range of you dataset? how many numbers do you have in one array?

Comment: 1+. This works for C++... But what if the language of choice is C?

Comment: The language of choice is C, yes

Comment: @Lyesmith If only C is what you want then please remove the `C++` tag. They are not the same language.

Comment: @Lyesmith And even if it is `C`, what does `unordered_set` do that makes it `O(n)`?  That's what you should investigate, and probably the answer that you're seeking.

Comment: @ Lyesmith, if your language is C, use a hash map, but you could implement by yourself, or you can find some opensource code from redis or others.

Comment: This is the right answer, but a description of the underlying implementation is required, since C would have to implement a custom unordered multiset.

Answer (score 1):

If the values of the elements in the array are small enough, you can keep an array of zeros `arr` of size equal to the maximum value in the arrays. Then for one array `A` you can iterate through the elements and mark the corresponding element in `arr` as `1`. Then for the other array `B`, do the same thing and check if there are any elements in `A` that are not in `B`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000
int arr[10000];
int scrambled( unsigned int a[], unsigned int b[], unsigned int len)
{
    if (len=0)
    {
    return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            arr[A[i]] = 1;
        }
        int same = 1;
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if(arr[B[i]] != 1)
                same = 0;
        }
        if (same)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else    
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The values of the elements are small enough, yes. They range from 0 to 99. That seems to work fine.

Comment: @Lyesmith That criteria of having a limited range of numbers was not stated in your original question.

Comment: That last `for` loop could be simplified to `for (int i=0; i<len; i++)  { if(arr[B[i]] != 1) return 0; } return 1;`

Comment: You can compress this "in common" list down by using a bit vector. For the full range of unsigned 32 bit integers, the _byte_ size of the bit vector is [at _most_]: `(1 << 32) / 8` or ~536 MB.

Comment: This method assumes the arrays have no duplicates: instead of setting to `1` you should increment by `1` in the first loop and decrement by `1` in the second loop and add a final loop to check that the array is all zeroes

Comment: This is known as a _counting sort_.

Comment: @CraigEstey: That only works if there are no duplicates. IOW, `{1,1,3}` and `{1,3,3}` would compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the arrays, you can sort them with radix sort and compare them with a simple `for` loop.  Radix sort has time complexity of **O(N*log(maxN))** where `maxN` is the maximum value of any number in the array. For an array of `unsigned int`, this maximum value is a constant, hence a time complexity of **O(N)**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not speak English and I'm not professional Developer

bet I now understand this problem.

I think this problem is you don't reset 'sumA', 'sumB' variable

sumA and sumB have a garbage value

I think you do that

```
int sumA = 0, sumB = 0, i;
```

Comment: That's not the issue here. The issue is, different sequences of elements can still have the same sum. Take a look at set and group theory if you're still having doubts about this.

Comment: Your remark is correct. You spotted an implementation bug. Unfortunately, this posted code is incorrect in more than one way: the algorithm is not appropriate to prove that the arrays contain the same values. Although it will detect many cases of mismatch, it would consider OK arrays such as `{0,3}` and `{1,2}`.

Comment: There is another obvious flaw in the posted code: `if (len = 0)` will set `len` to `0`. The function always returns `1`.